# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gymnasium' when gymnasium is installed

Tags: python-3.x

I am getting the "ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'gymnasium'" error when it is installed.

Trying to install gymnasium. I Expected my code to work, but when I run my code, I get
"  File "/home/sean/Desktop/Voyager/Voyager/voyager/env/bridge.py", line 9, in 
import gymnasium as gym
"

Comment: We have no idea on what it is such module, and how did you install it, so it is difficult to help. My guesses you installed not within the virtual environment you are using, or just a bug on the installation (or documentation) of the module